# Actor not stopped in `akka aggregator pattern` documentation

Tags: scala, akka

I read `the aggregator pattern` http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/contrib/aggregator.html  and find something in the `sample use case` paragraph

```
def fetchSavingsAccountsBalance() {
      context.actorOf(Props[SavingsAccountProxy]) ! GetAccountBalances(id)
      expectOnce {
        case SavingsAccountBalances(balances) ⇒
          results += (Savings -> balances)
          collectBalances()
      }
    }
```

I found the actor created by `context.actorOf` is never stopped, is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that stopping the aggregator actor is your own responsibility.  From the docs:

```
The aggregator should terminate after the response is sent (or timed out).
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that stopping is your own responsibility and not something the framework does for you.  I'm guessing that if it did stop itself, the docs would say something along the lines of:

```
The aggregator will terminate...
```

You will also notice that there are explicit calls to `context.stop` in the multiple examples from within the docs.  Also, the example you gave is part of a chained aggregation example.  It does a bunch of individual data collections (chained together) before finally responding with all of the aggregated data and explicitly stopping itself with this piece of code.

```
def processFinal(eval: List[Int]) {
  // Select only the entries coming back from eval
  originalSender ! FinalResponse(eval map values)
  context.stop(self)
}
```

Comment: You are right, the collectBalances method stop the aggregator

Answer (score 0):

Actors don't shutdown themselves by default unless you:

- stop the actor system `context.system.shutdown()`
- stop the parent actor or
- stop that actor explicitly with `context.stop(self)`.

Since you use aggregator pattern and need to collect results only once you can shutdown the whole actor system once processing is finished.